# LUKS partition mounts to a different folder

Tags: partitioning, mount, luks

I've made a LUKS partition on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 (unfortunately I can not recall which tutorial I used). The partition used to mount automatically at startup to `/media/$USER/mydata`. However, a few days ago I noticed some strange behavior and it turned out that the LUKS partition was now mounted to `media/$USER/mydata1`. Upon closer inspection I noticed the following icon on the original `mydata` folder which I can no longer open:

[image]

Note: I'm not mounting it using `/etc/fstab`.

Any ideas how this might have happened or have a possible solution?

### Edit 19 March 2017 14:14

Output of `lsblk -i`

```
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                              7:0    0    20K  0 loop  /snap/hello-world/27
loop1                              7:1    0  78,3M  0 loop  /snap/core/1441
loop2                              7:2    0  75,2M  0 loop  /snap/core/1287
loop3                              7:3    0  75,2M  0 loop  /snap/core/1337
nvme0n1                          259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
|-nvme0n1p1                      259:1    0   450M  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p2                      259:2    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
|-nvme0n1p3                      259:3    0    16M  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p4                      259:4    0  74,6G  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p5                      259:5    0 117,2G  0 part  
| `-luks-e3bb8546-0aec-4474-b2f2-2adf22d0d0e3
|                                252:0    0 117,2G  0 crypt /media/roald/mydata1
|-nvme0n1p6                      259:6    0   7,6G  0 part  [SWAP]
|-nvme0n1p7                      259:7    0  18,6G  0 part  /
`-nvme0n1p8                      259:8    0  18,6G  0 part  /home
```

Comment: Can you access your data from the second location?

Comment: @George Yes no problem.

Comment: please run `lsblk -i` and post

Comment: @George See post.

Comment: That situation is normal perhaps you didn't pay attention to it at creation, mine is the same with my mounted devices in `/media` dir

Comment: @George maybe I can delete the mydata folder and reboot? I don't know if it wise to delete it.

Comment: Is the data not important, and since you can access the data why delete it. Unless you have other issues as per access of data integrity?